# PUT in MVC Single Page App Template creating new object? Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking at the single-page web application for MVC4 from VS templates (from here http://www.asp.net/single-page-application) and it looks like the PUT action for ToDoLists is creating a new ToDoList - why is this?  The code from the DTO class definition:

```
public TodoList ToEntity()
        {
            TodoList todo = new TodoList
            {
                Title = Title,
                TodoListId = TodoListId,
                UserId = UserId,
                Todos = new List<TodoItem>()
            };
            foreach (TodoItemDto item in Todos)
            {
                todo.Todos.Add(item.ToEntity());
            }

            return todo;
        }
```

From the controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutTodoList(int id, TodoListDto todoListDto)
{           
    TodoList todoList = todoListDto.ToEntity();
    db.Entry(todoList).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

So to update a record, we create a new one?  I'm a little confused about how this is working - any clarification would be awesome.

Comment: Can you clarify what are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking - why not select the existing record and update it.  Why call ToEntity, which creates a new object in the database?

Comment: Because it would an unnecessary call to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, the controller is converting the `TodoListDto` object into a `TodoList` object, which is the database object type.  Since the DTO object is coming back from the web page, it has to be changed into the appropriate type so that Entity Framework can attach it to the DbSet and save changes.

`ToEntity` doesn't actually create a new record in the database, it creates a new `TodoList` instance which then gets attached, as modified to the database.